# need to rearrange and sum column in solaris command

Tags: awk, solaris

I have below data named atp.csv file

```
Date_Time,M_ID,N_ID,Status,Desc,AMount,Type
2015-01-05 00:00:00 076,1941321748,BD9010423590206,200,Transaction Successful,2000,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 077,1941323504,BD9010423590207,351,Transaction Successful,5000,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 078,1941321743,BD9010423590205,200,Transaction Successful,1500,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 391,1941323498,BD9010500000003,200,Transaction Successful,1000,PRETOP
```

i want to count status wise using below command.

```
cat atp.csv|awk -F',' '{print $4}'|sort|uniq -c
```

The output is like below:

```
3 200
1 351
```

But i want to like below output and also want to sum the amount column in status wise.

```
200,3,4500
351,1,5000
```

That is status is first and then count value.Please help..

Comment: If you are using Solaris, why have you tagged the question with Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWK has associative arrays.

```
% cat atp.csv | awk -F, 'NR>1 {n[$4]+=1;s[$4]+=$6;} END {for (k in n) { print k "," n[k] "," s[k]; }}' | sort
200,3,4500
351,1,5000
```

In the above:

1. The first line (record) is skipped with `NR>1`.
2. `n[k]` is the number of occurrences of key `k` (so we add 1), and `s[k]` is the running sum values in field 6 (so we add `$6`).
3. Finally, after all records are processed (`END`), you can iterate over associated arrays by key (`for (k in n) { ... }`) and print the keys and values in arrays `n` and `s` associated with the key.

Comment: Nice, +1. modified it a bit: awk -F, 'NR>1 {n[$4]++;s[$4]+=$6;} END {for (k in n) { print k, n[k], s[k]; }}' OFS="," atp.csv | sort

Comment: You don't need the semi colons at the end of the blocks or the `{` brackets around the print statement at the end.

Comment: P.s don't pipe `cat` into `awk`, it takes files as args anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yeah, it can be golfed down to fewer chars. On the note of using cat: it's slower at runtime, but personally I like working with a "cat ... |" pattern because frequently I'll want to adopt parts of a chain elsewhere, and it'd be a nasty surprise to discover that I accidentally ran "cat atp-2015.csv | awk '...' atp-2014.csv" :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk` version also

```
awk -F',' '{print $4,",", a[$4]+=$6}' FileName  | sort -r  | uniq -cw 6 | sort -r
```

**Output :**

```
  3 200 , 4500
  1 351 , 5000
```

**Another Way:**

```
awk -F',' '{print $4,",", a[$4]+=$6}' FileName  | sort -r | uniq -cw 6 |sort -r |  sed 's/\([^ ]\+\).\([^ ]\+\).../\2,\1,/'
```

Comment: `uniq -w 1` only compares the first character, this will fail if one of the input lines contained e.g. 201 in `$4`?

Comment: see my updated answer , `-w 6` matched until `6` character so the unique status id only printed

Comment: Have you tried that? This includes characters from the second column and no longer answers the OPs question. Until `uniq` gains a better concept of fields (which is in the works AFAIK) I don't think it  can easily be applied here.

Comment: uniq: illegal option -- w
Usage:  uniq [-c|-d|-u][-f fields][-s char] [input_file [output_file]]
Or:     uniq [-c|-d|-u][-n][+m] [input_file [output_file]]

Answer (score 0):

All in (g)awk

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{a[$4]++;b[$4]+=$6}
         END{n=asorti(a,c);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print c[i]","a[c[i]]","b[c[i]]}' file
```

Comment: gawk not installed on solaris (by default)